# ipc.HBaseRPC: Server at myhostname-ubuntu/myIP:myPort could not be reached after 1 tries, giving up

Tags: hbase

When I try to list all the tables through HBase shell it works as expected, but when I scan or create a new table from HBase shell, I get the following errors:

```
hbase(main):002:0> scan 'My_Table'
ROW                                         COLUMN+CELL                                                                                                                  
13/12/02 16:16:39 INFO ipc.HBaseRPC: Server at myhostname-ubuntu/myIP:myPort could not    be   reached after 1 tries, giving up.
```

My /etc/hosts/ :

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
XX.XX.XX.XX   myhostname-ubuntu
```

Thank you in advance !!!

Answer (score 1):

It seems one or more **HRegionServer is dead.**

If you check status by typing 'status' in hbase shell, you'll see the number of dead server.

For example,

```
$ hbsae shell
$ hbase(main):001:0> status
$ 0 servers, 1 dead, 4.0000 average load
```

If you can see one or more dead server, hbase will work properly after restart.

```
$ stop-hbase.sh
$ start-hbase.sh
```